# How come I get NA values after subsetting in R?

Tags: r, na, subset

Would you know why I get NA values after subsetting observations into a new data frame and how to solves this? Here is how I proceeded - feel free to let me know about any mistakes I may have made.

My data frame is LE2010. I've ranked the turnouts in ascending order and would like to select the first 5 and last 5 rows (those with highest and lowest turnout)

```
 head(LE2010)
      ward.name ward.code electorate votescast  turnout
 111   Haverstock E05000136       8621      3123 36.22550
 361   Courtfield E05000386       6407      2400 37.45903
 358     Brompton E05000383       5918      2362 39.91213
 365    Hans Town E05000390       6787      2722 40.10609
 370 Queen's Gate E05000395       6258      2565 40.98754
 363 Earl's Court E05000388       6514      2723 41.80227
 tail(LE2010)
  ward.name ward.code electorate votescast  turnout
 534 South   E05000559       7356      5589 75.97879
 535 Cheam   E05000560       7765      5929 76.35544
 499 Kew     E05000524       8212      6320 76.96055
 166 Southf. E05000191       8803      6803 77.28047
 99  Petts   E05000124      11000      8594 78.12727
 492 East    E05000517       7460      5871 78.69973
```

I then select the first 5 and last 5 rows (I wasn't certain how to do this properly so the mistake might come from here...

```
#Select the first 5 first and 5 last rows
LE2010.2 <- LE2010[1:5, ][620:624, ]
LE2010.2
 ward.name ward.code electorate votescast turnout
NA        <NA>      <NA>         NA        NA      NA
NA.1      <NA>      <NA>         NA        NA      NA
NA.2      <NA>      <NA>         NA        NA      NA
NA.3      <NA>      <NA>         NA        NA      NA
NA.4      <NA>      <NA>         NA        NA      NA
```

I now the values in my subset are NAs... Any idea why and how to solve this? Apologies in advance this is a newbie question :)

Thanks

Melody

Answer (score 2):

An explanation of *why* your code doesn't work:

```
LE2010.2 <- LE2010[1:5, ][620:624, ]
```

`LE2010[1:5, ]` grabs the first 5 rows of `LE2010`. This is the first thing you type, so this subset is performed first. When you stick more brackets on the end, you're trying to subset again, but the starting point is the subset you already made, so you try for the 620 through 624th row of the 5-row subset. As it only has 5 rows, NAs are returned.

As @cory says, `LE2010[c(1:5, 620:624), ]` will work, as you're only taking one subset. Another way to do it would be

```
rbind(head(LE2010, 5), tail(LE2010, 5))
```

I like using `tail` because you don't need to know how many rows there are, it just picks from the end. Here I'm taking two subsets and rbinding them together, but the subsets both reference the original object.

Comment: Great, that works AND I understand why thanks to you and Cory. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
LE2010.2 <- LE2010[c(1:5, 620:624), ]
```